# Angular issue with Q library

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following the tutorial related to Angular.js that is located on pluralsight.com. So far I did not have serious issues. Tutorials are very good and easy to follow. However, there is something that I cant resolve on my own. I would like my deffereds to react differently either on success or on fail. In this case they are always firing like they succeeded.

Service:

```
var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', {id: '@id'});
return {
    getEvent: function (id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        resource.get({id: id},
            function (event) {
                console.log("This is (EVENT): " + event);
                deferred.resolve(event);
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log("This is (RESPONSE): " + event);
                deferred.reject(response);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.event = eventData.getEvent(2)
         .then (
              function(event) {
                  $scope.event = event;

                  console.log(event);
              },
              function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              }
          );
```

In other words, if I send the wrong id (to load JSON file that does not exists) I want it to let me know that.

Comment: What HTTP Status Code is your 'failure' returning?  Which console.log do you see (which don't you see)?

Comment: Only thing I am seeing is: console.log("This is (EVENT): " + event); That is being fired always!

Comment: OK, what HTTP Status Code is your service returning?  Is it something other than a 200?

Comment: It is always 200. According to Fiddler

Comment: That is your issue.  A REST interface is said to be in error when the service returns something other than a 200.  Something in the range of 400 or 500 is considered an error.  So, `$resource` will never call the error function (unless the status code is not 200).

Answer (score 0):

The `$resource` service in angular wraps a call to the `$http` service applying some REST conventions to the HTTP request.  These are all documented [here in the $resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

When handling the promise from `$resource`, if the HTTP status code is 200, then the success callback will be executed.  Otherwise (if the HTTP status code is in the 400 or 500 range), the error callback will be executed.  This is a typical REST convention.

So, since your service is always returning 200 Status codes, `$resource` assumes that this is a successful server call and executes the success callback.

In order to handle this, you would need to use `$http` directly or change your service so that it returns the correct HTTP status code.

Hope this helps.